# run two scripts with user data on first server boot

Tags: cloud, init

i want to run two scripts using cloud init user data

the first command is for set root password

`

```
#cloud-config
chpasswd:
 list: |
   root:o~s@grnet
```

`

the second I want to set the password expired and force root to change the password.

How can I do that

i want to run two scripts

Comment: Are you using core18/core20 and ubuntu snaps?

Comment: I use ubuntu or any OS like Debian or CentOS. what I need is after set root password after the first login force root to change password

Comment: Well, ideally it should ask to reset the password after first login per this documentation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-cloud-config-scripting#change-passwords-for-existing-users

Comment: In cloud init documentation also: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-passwords

Comment: can I use runcmd: to execute command: passwd -e root